# Applying the Ratio Test

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

I am self-studying Real Analysis from the text *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott. I would like for someone to 1) verify my proof for parts (a) and (b) of the below exercise problem is rigorous and correct. Do you have a hint/clue for part (c) (without giving away or revealing the entire solution)?

> [Abbott 6.5.7] Let $\displaystyle \sum a_{n} x^{n}$ be a power series with $\displaystyle a_{n} \neq 0$, and assume that

\begin{equation*}
L=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| 
\end{equation*}

> exists.

(a) Show that if $\displaystyle L\neq 0$, then the series converges for all $\displaystyle x$ in $\displaystyle ( -1/L,1/L)$. (The advice in exercise 2.7.9 may be helpful).

***Proof.***

Fix $\displaystyle x_{0} \in ( -1/L,1/L)$ be an arbitrary point.

The absolute value ratio of the successive terms of the power series at the point $\displaystyle x_{0}$ is given by:

\begin{equation*}
\left| \frac{a_{n+1} x_{0}^{n+1}}{a_{n} x_{0}^{n}}\right| =\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| \cdot |x_{0} |
\end{equation*}
Passing to the limits, as $\displaystyle n\rightarrow \infty $, we have:

\begin{equation*}
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| \cdot |x_{0} |=L\cdot |x_{0} |< 1
\end{equation*}
If $\displaystyle L\ \neq 0$, then $\displaystyle 0< L\cdot |x_{0} |=r< 1$.

By the ratio test for the convergence of an infinite series of real numbers, $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} x_{0}^{n}$ converges. Since, $\displaystyle x_{0}$ was arbitrary, this holds true for all $\displaystyle x\in ( -1/L,1/L)$. Consequently, $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} x^{n}$ converges.

(b) Show that if $\displaystyle L=0$, then the series converges for all $\displaystyle x\in \mathbf{R}$.

***Proof.***

We are given that $\displaystyle L=0$. So, the $\displaystyle \lim \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| =0$. By definition of limits, this implies:

\begin{equation*}
( \forall \epsilon  >0)( \exists N\in \mathbf{N})( \forall n\geq N)\left(\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| < \epsilon \right)
\end{equation*}
Fix $\displaystyle x_{0} \in \mathbf{R}$. A power series always converges at $\displaystyle x=0$, so assume that $\displaystyle x_{0} \neq 0$.

Pick $\displaystyle \epsilon =\frac{1}{2|x_{0} |}$ and let $\displaystyle r=\frac{1}{2}$. Then, there exists $\displaystyle N\in \mathbf{N}$, such that for all $\displaystyle n\geq N$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| < \frac{1}{2|x_{0} |}
\end{equation*}
which is

\begin{equation*}
\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| |x_{0} |< \frac{1}{2} =r
\end{equation*}
Thus,

\begin{equation*}
|a_{n+1} x_{0}^{n+1} |< |a_{n} x_{0}^{n} |r
\end{equation*}
for all $\displaystyle n\geq N$.

Consequently,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ c l }
\sum _{n=N}^{\infty } |a_{n} x_{0}^{n} | & =|a_{N} x_{0}^{N} |\left( 1+r+r^{2} +\dotsc \right)\\
 & =\frac{|a_{N} ||x_{0}^{N} |}{1-r} \quad \left\{\text{Geometric series}\right\}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
Hence, $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} x_{0}^{n}$ is converges absolutely. By the absolutely convergence test, $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} x_{0}^{n}$ is a convergent series.

Since $\displaystyle x_{0}$ was arbitrary, this must be true for all $\displaystyle x\in \mathbf{R}$. Consequently, $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} x^{n}$ converges for all $\displaystyle x\in \mathbf{R}$.

(c) Show that (a) and (b) continue to hold if $\displaystyle L$ is replaced by the limit

\begin{equation*}
L'=\lim s_{n} \quad \text{where} \ \quad s_{n} =\sup \left\{\left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\right| :k\geq n\right\}
\end{equation*}

***Proof.***

Fix $\displaystyle x_{0} \in \left( -\frac{1}{L'} ,\frac{1}{L'}\right)$.

Define

\begin{equation*}
s_{n} =\sup \left\{\left| \frac{a_{k+1} x_{0}^{k+1}}{a_{k} x_{0}^{k}}\right| :k\geq n\right\} =\sup \left\{\left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\right| |x_{0} |:k\geq n\right\} =|x_{0} |\cdot \sup \left\{\left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\right| :k\geq n\right\}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
r_{n} =\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| |x_{0} |
\end{equation*}
We know that:

\begin{equation*}
r_{n} \leq s_{n}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s_n \geq |\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}|$ so $L'\geq L$. This implies that  $(-\frac 1 {L'}, 
\frac 1 {L'}) \subseteq (-\frac 1 {L},
\frac 1 L)$. This takes care of a) with $L$ repaced by $L'$.

If  $L'=0$ then $L=0$ so b) is also taken care of.

Comment: Ok, it looks like, I should assume the existence of the limit $\lim |a_{n+1}/a_n|$.